# Transition effect on expanding UL

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

How do i add a transition effect on this expanding list?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outerBG"> 
        <div class="innerBG">
            <h2 class="info">&#10148; Show text</h2>
            <ul id="infoContent" style="display:none">
                <li>TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1</li>
                <li>TEST 2 TEST 2 TEST 2 TEST 2</li>              
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using JavaScript to toggle the UL's display:

```
function expand () {
    infoContent.style.display = infoContent.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

Is it possible to make a transition effect out of this?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqy2c80u/

Comment: You can't transition or animate the `display` property.

Comment: nb. Due to the inability to interpolate intermittant points (its not an ordinal value), `display` cannot be transitioned/animated :(

Comment: No Javascript needed here, see my answer below. It even toggles the text from Show content to Hide content when visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `display: none` to animate elements into view.

However, you can update your `expand` function to the change the class from `open` to `close` like so:

**JavaScript Change:**

```
function expand () {
    infoContent.className = infoContent.className === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
}
```

And then apply the CSS animation using `max-height` (in case the content inside the animated div is dynamic):

**CSS Addition:**

```
#infoContent {
    margin: 0; // Remove the margins
    overflow: hidden;
}

#infoContent.close {
    max-height: 0; // Set max height to zero
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
}

#infoContent.open {
    max-height: 300px; /* Set max height as big as you think it will ever go */
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
}
```

**Demo:** [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mqy2c80u/5/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it made it a bit more clear for me.
Although the scroll bar keeps showing up when you toggle the overflow

Comment: It was an oversight on my part. I've moved it to the `#infoContent`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using CSS only, no Javascript required here.

https://jsfiddle.net/mqy2c80u/10/

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
}

.innerBG {
    width: 260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.outerBG {
    width: 260px;
    background-color: #4f322a;
    margin: 15px auto 25px auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #70463a;
}
.info {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.info h2:after {
    content:"Show content";
}
#demo {
    display: none;
}
#demo:checked ~ #infoContent {
    max-height: 400px;
}
#demo:checked + .info h2:after {
    content:"Hide content";
}
.innerBG h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: lato;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 100;
}
#infoContent {
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#infoContent li {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: lato;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="outerBG">
        <div class="innerBG">
            <input type="checkbox" id="demo" />
            <label class="info" for="demo">&#10148;
                <h2></h2>
            </label>
            <ul id="infoContent">
                <li>TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1</li>
                <li>TEST 2 TEST 2 TEST 2 TEST 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, you neither upvoted it nor did you choose it as the best answer to your problem. :( At least you checked it and said thanks :)

Comment: Corrected the example.

Comment: Sorry, Upvoted it now since its still a good solution. Reason i picked another answer/solution is because i didn't want a "fading" transition on the text. I Guess that wasn't clear in my question though.

Comment: I have removed the fading from the fiddle and from the snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a transition to `max-height` and toggle that and not `display`. The reason being that `display` is not an ordinal value so cannot be animated as transitional values cannot be interpolated. `max-height` is ordinal, so can be transitioned.

With that in mind, it is important to note that the 'show' value for `max-height` should be enough to accommodate the content, otherwise the transition will elongate. Its also better than animating on `height` as a known value is not required, the height will only grow to that required.

```js
var infoContent = document.getElementById("infoContent");
var info = document.querySelector(".info");

function expand() { // do this on maxHeight not display
  infoContent.style.maxHeight = infoContent.style.maxHeight ? 0 : '100px';
}

info.addEventListener("click", expand, false);
```

```css
.innerBG {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.outerBG {
  width: 260px;
  background-color: #4f322a;
  margin: 15px auto 25px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #70463a;
  overflow: auto;
}
.innerBG h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: lato;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#infoContent li {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: lato;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#infoContent {
  max-height: 0; /* collapse by default */
  overflow: hidden; /* <-- hide content when collapsed */
  transition: max-height 200ms; /* <-- animate on change */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="outerBG">
    <div class="innerBG">
      <h2 class="info">&#10148; Show text</h2>
      <ul id="infoContent">
        <li>TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1 TEST 1</li>
        <li>TEST 2 TEST 2 TEST 2 TEST 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```